# CAN interface up on Raspberry Pi 3B + issue

Tags: raspbian

I added this to the /boot/config.txt and now I have two CAN interfaces
#CAN bus controllers
dtoverlay=mcp2515-can0,oscillator=16000000,interrupt=25
dtoverlay=mcp2515-can1,oscillator=16000000,interrupt=24

dtoverlay=spi-bcm2835

and when below command is given
**sudo ip link set up can0 type can bitrate 500000**

the terminal hangs/stuck. even can't open ifconfig. Need to reboot every time and unable to link up the CAN. Could you please help

Answer (score 1):

I assume here your CAN driver's name is `mcp2515`. You can confirm that by looking at the device tree file or by checking the `lsmod` output.

First, see if the device driver actually loads using `lsmod | grep mcp2515`. I think it will load the SPI driver as a dependency, check if that is the case.

Second, look at the kernel log for error messages from your driver, e.g. with `sudo dmesg | grep mcp2515`. See if these messages make sense (they often do) and try to fix any reported errors.

Third, if the driver is reported as loaded by `lsmod`, use `modinfo mcp2515` or browse `/sys/module/mcp2515/parameters/` to see what parameters it has and what are the values.

Edit: according to the link you have found, this is a kernel issue with two possible fixes:

- downgrade to kernel 5.4
- patch the `mcp251x.c` driver, replacing `ret = mcp251x_hw_wake (spi);` by `ret = mcp251x_hw_reset (spi);`. Alternatively, it is suggested to remove the `disable_irq(spi->irq);` from the `mcp251x_hw_wake()` funciton.

Comment: Unable to link/configure the CAN bus. I'm using OS 5.10.79-v7+. Upon boot up, "failed to load overlay dtoverlay=spi-bcm2835" is displayed on the edge of the screen

Comment: same problem is observed here https://forum.armbian.com/topic/14909-orange-pi-mcp2515-ip-up-freezes/

Comment: @TheerthaBV Interesting. Did the fixes help?

Comment: i'm not from LINUX background. So, i'm on my way into LINUX and its structure. As it progresses i'll understand the things and will try to do the changes. Right now, CAN link is not established in the Raspberry PI 3B+

Comment: I believe It's not possible to downgrade the kernel to 5.4 (let me know if you have the info or link about this)

Comment: downgrade RPi os to Linux 5.4.61-v7+ by using command sudo rpi-update 039088f7d929b0d1cc49e8d2012df0652f908518 (CAN bus will link up and work)