# sudo command on Raspbian Terminal is hanging

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

When the `sudo` command is typed and pressed on the terminal, it's getting hanged.
Background:
I tried to establish the CAN link on the Raspberry PI board. Added CAN link connection command/script upon boot-up. For that, in `/etc/network/interface` I added the script below:

```
auto can0
  iface can0 inet manual
  pre-up /sbin/ip link set can0 type can bitrate 1000000
  up /sbin/ifconfig can0 up
  down /sbin/ifconfig can0 down
```

After this everything is not working. When I reboot the RPi board, it takes serveral minutes to boot up and the wifi doesn't work. Terminal works but stucks after sudo command. Please help!

Note: Any command run with `sudo` doesn't work, for example `sudo nano <file>`.

Comment: `sudo` is never just run without at least ONE argument - what exactly is the command you are running - also, can you see any errors in `dmesg` that may indicate why the pi is taking longer to boot?

Comment: so, all you did was add those five lines to `/etc/network/interface` and this has caused network failure and breaks `sudo`? You did nothing else?

Comment: yes, nothing else. Before editing interfaces file, just upgrade the installed packages (sudo apt-get update followed by upgrade). Also, after sudo command freezed every time, I tried to delete the added script from the file. Since it is root file, I couldn't delete it as root user is blocked/freezed/hanged(sudo)

Comment: put the sd card in another computer, edit the `cmdline.txt` file, adding `init=/bin/bash` to the end of the single line in that file - then put it back in your pi, boot, and issue the command `mount -o remount,rw / –target /` - now you can edit that file that's causing the problem, remove the `init=/bin/bash` from `cmdline.txt` and reboot - at least you'll now be back to a functional pi

Comment: DO NOT put anything into `/etc/network/interface` (unless you disable interface in `dhcpcd`)

Comment: @Bravo Thanks it worked now by following your instruction. But, could not find the the real cause. Mean while how to automate CAN link establishment/configuration upon bootup? The google article says what I did (inclusion in the /etc/network/interface)

Comment: did removing the CAN stuff from `/etc/network/interface` fix the sudo issue?

Comment: yes, sudo command worked. But, unable to link/configure the CAN bus. I'm using OS 5.10.79-v7+. Upon boot up, "failed to load overlay dtoverlay=spi-bcm2835" is displayed on the edge of the screen.

Comment: Any one can help on these ? any experts ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing to me. You do not explain what you mean by `the CAN link` - is this a *Controller Area Network*? If so, why are you provisioning an IP address for it? Did you get the "script" in your question from a tutorial or manufacturer's instructions? If so, you should supply a link (edit your question).

Assuming you're following competent instructions, and you do actually need to provision an IP address for this `CAN link`, please read on as you have **apparently** made one or more of the errors below. Otherwise please edit your question to explain your use case & we'll try to help.

1. Your question says you have edited the file `/etc/network/interface`, but ***this file does not exist in a default RPi OS image***. You may have this confused with the file: `/etc/network/interfaces` (note the 's') which is included in default RPi OS images.
2. The file `/etc/network/interfaces` contains the following line:

> # Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd.

Which is an awkward way of saying that you are not supposed to manually edit this file **if** you use the default network management tool `dhcpcd`.  Instead, you should use `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, and follow the syntax defined in `man dhcpcd.conf` to declare your interface.

3. You may be using the incorrect *Network Manager*. If `/etc/network/interfaces` is to be used as you've shown in your question, you will need to disable `dhcpcd`, and install or use another network manager; e.g. [`network-manager`](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-and-use-networkmanager-nmcli-on-ubuntu-debian/), [`systemd-networkd`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108592/use-systemd-networkd-for-general-networking/108593#108593).

Comment: same issue observed here ...https://forum.armbian.com/topic/14909-orange-pi-mcp2515-ip-up-freezes/

Comment: @TheerthaBV: Sorry - I've tried to explain why I feel your question is confusing - that question you've referenced in your comment doesn't help at all.

Comment: I'll come back to this ones this is got fixed .....https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/133329/can-interface-up-on-raspberry-pi-3b-issue